# Getting error on Joining Tables in TypeORM & NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm new to TypeORM and NestJs and i'm trying to join leave table with leave category table, but i'm getting error.

Here is my code.

**Leave.entity.ts**

```
import {Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany, OneToOne, JoinColumn  } from "typeorm";
import { tbLeaveRequestDetails } from "./leave.entity";

@Entity("tbLeaveType")
export class tbLeaveType {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    intLeaveTypeId : number;
    
    @Column({ nullable: true, default: null, length: 300})
    vchLeaveTypeName: string;

    @Column()
    intNumberOfLeaves: number;

    @Column()
    TypeStatus: number;


    @OneToMany(type => tbLeaveRequestDetails, image => image.type)
    leave: tbLeaveRequestDetails[];

}
```

**LeaveType.entity.ts**

```
import {Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany, JoinColumn, JoinTable, OneToOne  } from "typeorm";
import { tbLeaveType } from "./leaveType.entity";

@Entity("tbLeaveRequestDetails")
export class tbLeaveRequestDetails {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    intLeaveRequestId : number;
    
    @Column()
    intRegistrationId: number;

    @Column()
    intLeaveTypeId: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => tbLeaveType, type => type.leave)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'intLeaveTypeId'})
    type: tbLeaveType;
    
}
```

**Leave.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { tbLeaveType } from "../Entities/leaveType.entity";
import { tbLeaveRequestDetails } from "../Entities/leave.entity";


@Injectable()
export class leaveService {
 
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(tbLeaveRequestDetails) private leave: Repository<tbLeaveRequestDetails>,
    @InjectRepository(tbLeaveType) private  leaveType: Repository<tbLeaveType>,
  ){}
  
  async getLeaves(): Promise<any> {
    try {

      const query = await this.leave.createQueryBuilder('leave')
      .innerJoinAndSelect("leave.leave", "leavetype");

      return query.getQuery();
    } catch(error){
      throw new NotFoundException('Error in Getting ', error);
    }
  }

}
```

Why this code getting error...?
Anybody, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: show the error you're getting

Comment: I'm getting this errror...
{
"statusCode": 404,
"message": "Error in Getting ",
"error": {}
}

Comment: shouldn't this be like this :  `import { tbLeaveRequestDetails } from "../Entities/leaveType.entity";
` and this `import { tbLeaveType } from "../Entities/leave.entity";`  in `usersService` ?

Comment: @BhargavGohil Then?